# Fourier integral problem?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Show that 
$$ 
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin \pi \omega \sin x\omega}{1-\omega^2}d\omega=
\begin{cases}
\frac{\pi}{2}\sin x,&\mbox{ if } 0\leq x\leq\pi\\
\quad\\
0,&\mbox{ if } x\geq\pi
\end{cases}
$$

Here is what I did 
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\sin x,&\mbox{ if } 0\leq x\leq\pi\\
\quad\\
0,&\mbox{ if } x\geq\pi
\end{cases}
$$
Then I tried to compute the integral

$$
\int_0^{\infty}[A(\omega)\cos(\omega x)+B(\omega)\sin(\omega x)]d\omega
$$

But I never reach my target. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have defined $f$ as follows 
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\sin x,&\mbox{ if } |x|\leq\pi\\
\quad\\
0,&\mbox{ if } |x|\geq\pi
\end{cases}
$$
So, $A(\omega)$ and $B(\omega)$ are going to be evaluated from $-\pi$ to $\pi.$ The rest is straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach.

1)Write the integral as

> $$ I = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \pi \omega \sin x\omega}{1-\omega^2}d\omega = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \pi \omega \sin x\omega}{(1-\omega)(1+\omega)}d\omega $$

and then you need to use the Parseval's identity

> $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(w)g(w)dw =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(t)G(t)dt. $$

See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1207038/calculating-value-of-integral-of-convolution-using-fourier-transform/1207048#1207048).